# Simulate Motorcycle Speedo Sensor

Tags: sensor, esp32, square-wave-voltametry

I had my motorcycle speedo replaced under warranty, but the dealer was not able to set the start milage, so I’m back to 0 km, which really annoys me. Instead of Ferris Buellering it for 10,000 km I’d like to simulate the signal from the speed sensor using an ESP32 with some basic micropython. This is the info I have from my tests:

On the Bike:

- Speed sensor has 3 wires. Red, Black and Green
- Voltage with ignition on but no wheel movement:

  - Red to Black  -10.3 VDC
  - Red to Green  +70 mVDC
  - Green to Black -10.4 VDC
- Scope probe attached to Red, ground to Green, with manual spin of the wheel (speedo registers speed and distance). Frequency changes based on speed. Seems to be 50% duty cycle.

[image: scope1]

- Probe attached to Green, ground to Black

[image: Scope2]

On the ESP 32:

- Square wave generated with Micropython (probe on output pin, ground to ESP32 Ground).

[image: Scope3]

- ESP32 is powered externally by USB.
  I thought I could just connect the ESP32 to the sensor (output pin to sensor Red, Ground to Senor Green), but no luck.

Is there a workable solution in here somewhere?

Comment: why would you want to have a motorcycle with 20,000 km on it? ... that inreases the depreciation

Comment: It's a cheap Honda, so the 10,000km extra makes no difference really.